# lavaan ERROR: model is a list, but not a parameterTable? in lavaan, Rstudio

Tags: r, r-lavaan

## What I'm doing

- I'm trying to do Structural Equation Model(cross-lagged effect model) with panel data.

## My code

```
model_jes3 <- '
#latent:internal, institution  observed:INFLU, COMPLEX, PARTY, ELECTION, CONGRESS
internal1 =~ 1*INFLU1 + COMPLEX1;
institution1 =~ 1*PARTY1 + ELECTION1 + CONGRESS1;
internal2 =~ 1*INFLU2 + COMPLEX2 ;
institution2 =~ 1*PARTY2 + ELECTION2 + CONGRESS2;

internal2 ~ internal1 + institution1;
institution2 ~ internal1 + institution1;
'
#The observed variables are 4 or 5 scales ordinal variables
crossA_D <- jes3A_D %>%
  sem(model_jes3, ordered = c("PARTY1","ELECTION1", "CONGRESS1", 
                                 "INFLU1", "COMPLEX1", "NOCARE1", 
                                 "PARTY2","ELECTION2", "CONGRESS2", 
                                 "INFLU2", "COMPLEX2", "NOCARE2"))
```

## Problem

- But I get an error message as following:

```
lavaan ERROR: model is a list, but not a parameterTable? 
lavaan NOTE: missing column(s) in parameter table: [lhs, op, rhs, free]
```

- What is parameterTable?
- Is there a problem in the model? I succeeded in the same analysis with almost the same data and mode.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and was a simple error. It seems I named the model the same as the dataframe and so Lavaan was reading the data frame instead of the actual model. Hope it helps.